# Toshiba satellite L755 nvidia resolution + boot problem

Tags: boot, 14.04, nvidia, xorg, resolution

I don't have alot of experience in linux, I tried all the solution I could find before asking this, here it goes:

I recently got a new Toshiba laptop, today I installed ubuntu 14.04LTS alongside of windows 7, and it completed successfully, then I encoutered the following:

1- The resolution was low (640X480), couldn't change it from settings->display, it's the only option.

2- I installed the nvidia driver by running  `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`, then rebooted, grub menu appear, then just a blank screen appear and it hang on it.

3- Went into root shell and uninstalled it by running `apt-get remove nvidia-current`, uninstalled ok, restarted, encountered the same problem, only a login in command-line appear and when I try to login it goes to a blank screen again.

4- Again went into root shell and ran `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`. Just excuted the command and nothing appeared, still have the same problem.

5- Reinstalled ubuntu using livestick, went back to low resolution, opened settings->software & updates->Additional drivers and I found out that it's using xserver-xorg-video-nouveau which only have low resolution.

6- Installed the nvidia-331 binary, rebooted, had the same blank screen.

which driver should I install?

Comment: found the solution and everything about the problem here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/is-a-nvidia-geforce-with-optimus-technology-supported-by-ubuntu